# Encode json file using with open

Tags: python, json

I am using `with open` to open my json file and parse data from it, however some characters aren't ascii. I google around and found that you have to set `encoding='utf8'` in `with open()`, so I do this and get this error

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xf6' in position 21: ordinal not in range(128)
```

So I figure I have to use `ensure_ascii=False` but then I get *this* error

```
TypeError: 'ensure_ascii' is an invalid keyword argument for open()
```

As you can see by the error ensure_ascii isn't compatible with `open()` but I don't know what is and I seem to be stuck and unable to find it.

The code being used

```
with open("languages.json", 'r', encoding='utf8') as f:
    languages = json.load(f)
with open("config.json", 'r', encoding='utf8') as c:
    config = json.load(c)
```

Comment: Which python version and json package you've used? Python 3 uses UTF-8 for opening by default and `ensure_ascii` is a param for json.

Comment: `ensure_ascii` is a param for `json.dump` that opposites of load, also not all json packages implement it. So it's not your case either. Try to do `data = f.read(); json.loads(data)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that `utf8` is not the correct keyword, instead use `utf-8` in your `encoding=`

Comment: Could you show me any of the .json files? Also, don't use ensure_ascii; there's no need.

Comment: "deutsch": {
        "2": "Subject: Antrag auf Löschung personenbezogener Daten
}

is one of them

Comment: This line here works fine for me: `with open("test.json", "r", encoding="UTF-8") as i:` where test.json is `{"deutsch": { "2": "Subject: Antrag auf Löschung personenbezogener Daten" }}`

Comment: There is no difference in spelling between utf8, utf-8, and UTF-8 for Python.